# Filter icon missing from Chrome Developer tools console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Typically when I view the console tabs within Chromes developer tools I have the option to select the "filters" icon that will allow me to filter for specific messages. This past week I noticed this was missing.

Open developer tools > select "console" > next to "clear console" is where the "filters" button should be.

[image: Missing Filters within console tab - Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: https://crbug.com/717776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an intentional change.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes#console

There's an active discussion about it on the mailing list. If you don't like it, this is the best place to voice your perspective:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/kH3FiDLlsFg